# npx create-react-app not working -- everything is deprecated

Tags: reactjs, npm, deprecated

Starting this morning, whenever I run the command `npx create-react-app project-name`, I am getting the below code block errors. I've tried: clearing cache, removing and reinstalling node, removing npx create-react-app globally...

**`npm : v8.3.0  node: v16.13.1  Running on macOS Monterey`**

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0061: │ babel-eslint@npm:10.1.0 is deprecated: babel-eslint is now u/babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
➤ YN0032: │ fsevents@npm:2.3.2: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0061: │ rollup-plugin-babel@npm:4.4.0 is deprecated: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use u/rollup/plugin-babel.
➤ YN0061: │ querystring@npm:0.2.1 is deprecated: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
➤ YN0061: │ u/hapi/joi@npm:15.1.1 is deprecated: Switch to 'npm install joi'
➤ YN0061: │ chokidar@npm:2.1.8 is deprecated: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
➤ YN0061: │ fsevents@npm:1.2.13 is deprecated: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
➤ YN0061: │ svgo@npm:1.3.2 is deprecated: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
➤ YN0061: │ querystring@npm:0.2.0 is deprecated: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
➤ YN0061: │ urix@npm:0.1.0 is deprecated: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
➤ YN0061: │ u/hapi/address@npm:2.1.4 is deprecated: Moved to 'npm install u/sideway/address'
➤ YN0061: │ u/hapi/bourne@npm:1.3.2 is deprecated: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
➤ YN0061: │ u/hapi/topo@npm:3.1.6 is deprecated: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
➤ YN0061: │ u/hapi/hoek@npm:8.5.1 is deprecated: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
➤ YN0032: │ nan@npm:2.14.2: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0061: │ core-js@npm:2.6.12 is deprecated: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
➤ YN0061: │ uuid@npm:3.4.0 is deprecated: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic. See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
➤ YN0061: │ flatten@npm:1.0.3 is deprecated: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
➤ YN0061: │ sane@npm:4.1.0 is deprecated: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
➤ YN0061: │ resolve-url@npm:0.2.1 is deprecated: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
➤ YN0032: │ evp_bytestokey@npm:1.0.3: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0061: │ request@npm:2.88.2 is deprecated: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
➤ YN0061: │ request-promise-native@npm:1.0.9 is deprecated: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
➤ YN0061: │ har-validator@npm:5.1.5 is deprecated: this library is no longer supported
➤ YN0002: │ react-dev-utils@npm:11.0.4 doesn't provide typescript (p79ddf), requested by fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
➤ YN0002: │ react-dev-utils@npm:11.0.4 doesn't provide webpack (p2af19), requested by fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
➤ YN0000: │ Some peer dependencies are incorrectly met; run yarn explain peer-requirements <hash> for details, where <hash> is the six-letter p-prefixed code
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 24s 290ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0013: │ yargs-parser@npm:13.1.2 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yargs-parser@npm:18.1.3 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yargs@npm:13.3.2 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yargs@npm:15.4.1 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yocto-queue@npm:0.1.0 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 2s 306ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0000: │ ESM support for PnP uses the experimental loader API and is therefore experimental
➤ YN0007: │ core-js@npm:3.9.0 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ core-js-pure@npm:3.9.0 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ fsevents@patch:fsevents@npm%3A1.2.13#~builtin<compat/fsevents>::version=1.2.13&hash=18f3a7 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ ejs@npm:2.7.4 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ core-js@npm:2.6.12 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 6s 29ms
➤ YN0000: Done with warnings in 32s 871ms
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'react-scripts/scripts/init.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/jaredriver/Desktop/basics/[eval]
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at [eval]:2:20
at Script.runInThisContext (node:vm:129:12)
at Object.runInThisContext (node:vm:305:38)
at node:internal/process/execution:75:19
at [eval]-wrapper:6:22
at evalScript (node:internal/process/execution:74:60) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [ '/Users/jaredriver/Desktop/basics/[eval]' ]
}
Aborting installation.
node  has failed.
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `react-scripts` first:

```
npm init -y && npm i react-scripts
```

Then run `npx`:

```
npx create-react-app app-name
```

Then you should be able to `cd` into your app:

```
cd app-name
```

Answer (score 0):

So to fix the error you're getting, uninstall create-react-app globally, update npm, clear the cache, and retry creating the app.

Run this in your terminal:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app && npm i -g npm@latest && npm cache clean -f && npx create-react-app@latest my-app --use-npm
```